# Disabling ATI auto-contrast and auto-brightness

Tags: laptop, amd-graphics-card

My HP Elitebook has an ATI video card with an *infuriating* feature that changes the contrast and the brightness in response to what's being shown on the screen. This has the result that the brightness changes constantly, and most web pages look washed out. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Disable Varibright. [Here is more info.](http://web.archive.org/web/20150906194620/http://aps2.toshiba-tro.de/kb0/HTD2503BA0001R01.htm)

Comment: Do you think you can add more information to this? SO (and stackexchange in general) tries to avoid link-only questions.